# Where is the location Mac OS store keyboard layout?

Tags: linux, macos, keyboard

I have the question as the title. In Ubuntu or Linux, I changed my keyboard layout. **change** I mean I actually remap entire keyboard. For example, I map the `tab` key to `ctrl`, assign `third-level key` to `caps`, so that when I press `caps` (it's now the `third-level key`) and `h`, it prints `{`.

And in Linux, it stores keyboard layout in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`.
So where is the location in the Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

In System Preferences | Keyboard | Modifier Keys you can swap keys